# spring boot About sensitive configuration files, automated packaging management

Tags: spring-boot

spring boot About sensitive configuration files, automated packaging management.

Question: For projects built using the spring boot framework, information about the formal environment is configured through application-prod.properties (for example: connections to databases, redis, etc.). These information are relatively sensitive and do not want to be seen by developers.

My current approach is that application-prod.properties is not included in the project. Create config in the same directory of the server jar, and then the operation and maintenance personnel manually edit the connection information in application-prod.properties.

I want to ask if there is a better way to achieve such a demand？

Comment: The Spring Boot documentation has a whole chapter on Externalizing Configuration. E.g you can encrypt the configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Well, thanks, encryption configuration is also a better security measure, but currently the team using the spring boot framework development project, whether there is a more mainstream solution. I want to know more about it as a reference.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, but I do not understand the question. All ways to externalize the configuraiton in a Spring Boot application are listed in the link I provided and they are mainstream solutions to this problem.

Comment: Well, the official document you provide provides a variety of solutions for the external configuration of spring boot. I am currently using [2.3. Application Property Files].
The official instructions you provided are very useful.
I don't know whether there are other ideas or frameworks for managing and configuring with spring boot besides the official solutions.